# C++ IDE migration from VS 6 to VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

A C++ project can be compiled by VS6 without errors&warnings.
With VS 2013 Prof., linker problems are occuring. They are providing a pattern namely std::basic_string.

The code was written in 2007 but not by me.

Referenced by a constructor:

> vrun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport)  public: char const * __thiscall
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator >::c_str(void)const " (__imp_?c_str@?$basic_s
>   tring@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ)
>   referenced in fun ction "public: __thiscall VTrs::VTrs(class
>   VMessageContext &)" (?? 0VDMTrs@@QAE@AAVVDMMessageHandlerContext@@@Z)

In vrun.cpp:

```
VTrs::VTrs(VMessageContext& handler_):
Inherited(RXS::rName().c_str()),
_handler(handler_)
{
}
```

(`c_str` -> `const char* c_str() const;` --- C98 style --- C11 was not applied in the project till yet)

In vrun.h:

```
VTrs(VMessageContext&);
```

Referenced by an operator:

```
vrun.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
 public: int __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,cl
ass std::allocator<char> >::compare(char const *)const " (__imp_?compare@?$basi
c_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEHPBD@Z) referenced in
 function "bool __cdecl std::operator==<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,clas
s std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<c
har>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,char const *)" (??$?8DU?$char_traits@
D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YA_NABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$a
llocator@D@2@@0@PBD@Z)
```

Refers -as far as interpreted- to a standard operator. (No operator overloading done for `==` which refers to a string)

By the way, the code itself does not contain "`std::basic_string`".
The according msdn article was read but this issue was not resolved till yet.

'Usual' issues such as the `"C"` modifier modifications are already considered for another code.

Any hint how to cope with that?

EDIT: When opening the project the first time with Visual Studio 2013, a kind of conversion dialog was displayed. I agreed but it affected the VC++ Directories. It was visible when comparing the project file with ClearCase to the previous verison. UndoCheckout (via ClearCase) applied the old state. Now it works.

Comment: RXS::rName().c_str() sure looks like std::basic_string::c_str to me

Comment: string::c_str() is an inline function, you should never have a link dependency on it.  I can only guess that you are compiling with an old version of the `<string>` header.  Use the /showIncludes compile option and make sure that all header files come from the right directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening the project the first time with Visual Studio 2013, a kind of conversion dialog was displayed. I agreed but it affected the VC++ Directories. It was visible when comparing the project file with ClearCase to the previous version. UndoCheckout (via ClearCase) applied the old state. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your linker needs to get the newer MSVC std library from the relevant lib file and it should pick this up when you migrate the project.   Take a look at Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input and make sure "Ignore All Default Libraries" is set to No